# Вывод Push в активити

Tags: android, google-api, pushup

Подскажите пожалуйста,как в таком коде сделать открытие Пуша в активити?То есть чтобы при нажатии на пуш,всю его инфу выводило в активити?

```
package com.developerhouse.push;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        createNotification(message);
    }

    // Creates notification based on title and body received
    private void createNotification(String body) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        long[] pattern = {500};

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
            .setContentTitle("UrbanSide PUSH").setVibrate(pattern)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setSound(sound);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("body", body);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: А в main активити надо теперь его ловить через гет?

Comment: да, String body = getIntent().getStringExtra("body");